# How to save uploaded image in an content type to picasa?

Tags: 7, nodes, media

I am uploading an image in a content type and I want that image to saved in picasa web albums.

While showing that node, I want the image to be displayed from picasa. Is there any module available for that or how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

> [Picasa Node Album](https://drupal.org/project/picasa_node_album) module provides gallery support in the form of
>   associating Picasa albums with nodes.

Features

- Link any public Picasa album to a node
- Thumbnail view with a template you can override
- Lightbox2 support already in the default template
- Select albums of the current Picasa account with autocomplete
- Supported node types configured via admin settings
- Define if thumbs should show on teasers and/or page views
- Define how many images in the gallery should be displayed on teasers/page views
- Define the sizes of thumbnails and images to request from Picasa
- Define whether you want an Albums tab on the node or not
- Image data results cache with a defined expiration
- Restrict what picasa accounts content can come from
- Restrict how many albums a user can upload per node

Comment: I want the image which is getting uploaded in a node, to be submitted to picassa. I don't know whether this module does that. I tried installing this module and its dependencies(libraries,Zend). Then i tried installing all versions of zend framework but i am getting error saying some path issue w.r.t zend module.